# How can I call a method on another Activity?

Tags: android, listview

I've tried creating a new instance of the Activity, but that doesn't seem right and seems like it'd cause more harm than good - and also doesn't work, so yea. That being said, I've got a method to populate a ListView on one activity, with a button that should add something to that list on another. I'm trying to figure out how I can call the method from the other Activity. I've tried to apply static, but some of the code within the methods says that it 'cannot be referenced from a static context'.

Here's the code I'm trying to call from another method:

```
CharacterDatabaseAdapter charDB;



 public void populateListView() {
        Cursor cursor = charDB.getAllRows();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {CharacterDatabaseAdapter.CHARACTER_NAME,
            CharacterDatabaseAdapter.CHARACTER_CLASS,
            CharacterDatabaseAdapter.CHARACTER_LEVEL};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.row_name, R.id.row_class, R.id.row_lvl};
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.character_overview_list_display, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);

    ListView charList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.charListView);
    charList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

Comment: You need to read up on Activities and Activity lifecycle a bit more. An activity that isn't visible, isn't available. Simple as that. If you want to add data to a list that will be displayed in another activity, then you need to keep that data *separate* from the activities and use the activity to simply do what they are designed to do: display data.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I'm doing is precisely what you mean, but I think I'm doing so. I've got a separate class named CharacterDatabaseAdapter that does the heavy lift - sets up the database, and does everything necessary to maintain it. Hence why I use the CharacterDatabaseAdapter at the top of the referenced code.

Comment: If you are doing that, then your question doesn't need to be asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on another activity because activities hold their own lifecycle and the other one can be not alive for whatever reason at the time you try to call it. So, what you need here is to know about Intents, that's the way activities (and other Android objects) communicate each other.

You can send data from one activity to another using intents and in the new activity you processed the received data.

[Here](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/passing-data-between-activities.html) You got a very complete example of the usage of Intents.